# How can I filter rows that match at least 3 conditions out of 5 variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, filtering, subset

I have a data set which contains 4 string variables and 1 boolean:

1. Mobile device
2. Budget
3. Car brand
4. Age
5. Interested

Each string variable can have four different values, for example the car brand can have: "BMW", "Mercedes", "Audi" or "Porsche".

For each variable, there is a prefered value, for example for the car brand it would be: "Audi", I am able to create a subset with the prefered value for one variable and or more, however I would like to create a subset which contains the rows in which conditions match at least 3 out of the 5 variables.

I tried using the filter function form the dplyr package, however I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of one approach with a built-in data set. When treated as a number, TRUE is 1, so we can add together a variety of tests. In this case the tests are based on numeric columns but you could use `brand == "Audi"` to test for a match against one target value or `brand %in% c("Audi", "Mercedes")` if multiple different values could count as a match.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(matches = (mpg > 25) + (cyl == 4) + (hp < 100) + (vs == 1) + (carb == 4)) %>%
  filter(matches >= 3)
```

Or more concisely:

```
mtcars %>% 
  filter((mpg > 25) + (cyl == 4) + (hp < 100) + (vs == 1) + (carb == 4) >= 3)
```